# Can someone suggest best way to learn fast groovy on grails 3

Tags: grails, groovy

I have experience in java but new to groovy and grails, please suggest me the best way to learn groovy and grails 3.0 and suggest IDE as well. Currently i knew about STS for groovy and IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: `experience in java`  and `i knew about STS` all very generic don't you think. Do you feel you have provided enough information ? How does anyone know what your level of understanding of any of those are and where you need to start. Try googling `grails 3 tutorial ` and work on what matches your needs.

Comment: It's pretty outdated but there is a book, Groovy and Grails Recipes by Bashar Abdul-Jawad, that was a great starting point for me

Comment: Grails in Action is a fantastic book, but it covers 2.3.7 not 3. Most of the skills would transfer over to 3 though

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ works fine, and the best way to learn something is to actually do it. Build an application -- a real one that solves a task you want to achieve, not following someone else's 12-step twitter bot or whatever.  Read up on groovy and grails to learn the idiomatic ways to accomplish tasks. Google is your friend.

My two cents.